# open new terminal results in editing bash_aliases file

Tags: command-line, bash, vim, git, alias

I got my git aliases in my `.bash_aliases` file. Since yesterday, when I want to add alias like `alias gpuo='git push --set-upstream origin'`. First, he doesn't find it and secondly, he open ups this file every time I open up a new terminal window. Also, I get prompted with 2 files to edit. But there is only one bash alias file. I checked it with the find command.

The contents of `.bash_aliases` are:

```
alias g='git'
alias gst='git status'
alias ga='git add'
alias gb='git branch'
alias gc='git checkout'
alias gcb='git checkout -b'
alias gpo='git push origin'
alias gf='git fetch'
alias gcm='git commit -m'
alias gp='git pull'
alias grom='git rebase origin/master'
alias gstash='git stash'
alias gstasha='git stash apply'
alias upgrade='sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get autoremove'
alias cl='clear'
alias alias='vim ~/.bash_aliases'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original poster found the solution while inspecting `~/.bash_aliases` and [provided it in an edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1168646/revisions):

> As I rewriting my question as suggested in the comments, I noticed there where an alias which I called `alias`. That caused recursive behavior. Thanks for the push in the correct direction ;)

To expand on that a bit, this was the line in `~/.bash_aliases` that caused the problem, which could simply be removed:

```bsh
alias alias='vim ~/.bash_aliases'
```

Strictly speaking, the problem was not caused by recursion. `bash` does not expand aliases recursively. For example, most Ubuntu users have `alias ls='ls --color=auto'`, and this does not cause any problems; the `ls` in the alias definition is not itself expanded.

Instead, the problem with defining an alias called `alias` is that subsequent attempts to use the `alias` command to define aliases use the `alias` alias instead. In this case, running `alias ...` had the effect of running `vim ~/.bash_aliases ...`, which would run `vim` and open `~/.bash_aliases` while also trying to open files named by the arguments passed for `...`.

When the `alias` command is used in the usual way to define aliases, it has one argument (e.g., `gpuo='git push --set-upstream origin'`). This explains the observation that two files were opened:

> Also, I get prompted with 2 files to edit.

If such files were saved, their names would have an `=` sign in them. It might be worth looking for such files to check that they were created unintentionally and then delete them. But if they weren't saved, `vim` would not have created them.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I wouldn't be able to explain this in that manner.